# have trouble calling last row and entering a number

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a simple code to go to the bottom of a row and enter a number, that allows the number to be added beneath the last line filled in. The code I have is

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+u
'
    Dim LR As Integer
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range(LR).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "30"
    Range("A229").Select
End Sub
```

I keep getting an error. Please help me assign the Last row LR

Comment: `Range("A" & LR).Value = 30`. Also use `Dim LR As Long`.

Comment: You could use this one-liner: `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = 30`. If you need the value as text (string) then use a preceding single quote: `"'30"`.

Comment: Thanks for the assist. Actually came up with answer of cahnging 2nd range to read: Range ("A" & LR + 1).Select